# Restore shows tape volume error

Tags: filesystems, rhel5, backup-restoration, restore

I have used the below command to take dump on my RHEL server:

```
/sbin/dump -0uz -f /data0101/backup_labeir1/labeir1_150622_123050_^apps.dmp /apps
```

The dump is successful, but when I do a restore using the below command it gives the error:

```
[root@labeir1 apps]# restore -rf /data0101/backup_labeir1/labeir1_150622_123050_^apps.dmp .
```

Error:

```
Dump tape is compressed.
restore: Tape is not volume 1 of the dump
```

I tried googling, but don't find any resolution to this issue. Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried restoring interactively with verbosity and debug turned up with the flags `-ivfd` ?

Comment: @GeraintJones : `[root@labeir1 apps]# restore -ivfd /data0101/backup_labeir1/labeir1_150622_123050_^apps.dmp .`gives me  `Verify tape and initialize maps
restore: d: No such file or directory`
    `[root@labeir1 apps]# restore -ivf /data0101/backup_labeir1/labeir1_150622_123050_^apps.dmp .`
`Verify tape and initialize maps
Input is from a local file/pipe
Input block size is 10
Dump tape is compressed.
Dump   date: Mon Jun 22 12:37:20 2015
Dumped from: the epoch
Level 0 dump of /apps on labeir1:/dev/cciss/c0d0p7
Label: /apps
restore: Tape is not volume 1 of the dump`

Comment: can you try `-ivMf` ?

Comment: @GeraintJones : No help. The error is weird: `# restore -ivMf /data0101/backup_labeir1/labeir1_150622_123050_^apps.dmp .` This command gives: 
`Verify tape and initialize maps
restore: /data0101/backup_labeir1/labeir1_150622_123050_^apps.dmp001: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Maybe its the carat `^` in the name ? I would suggest renaming it just in case.

Comment: @GeraintJones : But the dump file is in correct path `/data0101/backup_labeir1/labeir1_150622_123050_^apps.dmp`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25558/discussion-between-geraint-jones-and-dig-123).

Comment: @GeraintJones : Ahh maybe. Let me try a \ before the `^` in the name.

Comment: @GeraintJones : Sorry not able to login chat for some reasons. However the renaming of file and then trying `restore -ivMf ` also didn't help. Gives:

`# restore -ivMf /data0101/backup_labeir1/apps.dmp .
Verify tape and initialize maps
restore: /data0101/backup_labeir1/apps.dmp001: No such file or directory`